# Dectect ASCII codes for asian double byte / cyrillic character sets?

Tags: character-encoding, internationalization, rss, ascii, double-byte

Is it possible to detect if an ascii character belongs to Asian double byte or Cyrillic character sets? Perhaps specific code ranges? I've googled, but not finding anything at first glance.

There's an RSS feed I'm tapping into that has the locale set as 'en-gb'. But there are some Asian double byte characters in the feed itself - which I need to handle differently. Just not sure how to detect it since the meta locale data is incorrect. I do not have access to correct the public feed.

Comment: ASCII encoding doesn't support those characters, you might be wanting UTF-8.

Comment: Right, thanks. Ultimately I've got a string and need to determine if it has non-EN characters in it. A JS or Actionscript3 based detection is what I'm going to need, but I'll take any code snippets at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If your rss feed uses utf-8, which it probably does - just look that character value is greater than 255.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google suggest that you might wanna look at [String.charCodeAt](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#charCodeAt%28%29)

I don't know ActionScript, but I would expect a code snippet to look something like

```js
var stringToTest : String;

for each (var i : Number = 0; i < stringToTest.length; i++) {
    if (stringToTest.charCodeAt(i) > 255) {
        // Do something to your double-byte character here
    } else {
        // You have a plain ASCII character here
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!